# Has someone used async ctp in production

Tags: async-ctp

Would be glad to see some feedback from you in using async ctp in developing or even production.

We are starting big project and pay much attention to async programming model, so we are going to make our code 4.5  features ready buy using async ctp.

So have somebody faceoff some problems with it?

P.S. we can't use 4.5 beta in case of azure and visual studio aspects/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you against using the CTP in production, because it contains [at least one serious bug](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/10/eduasync-part-10-ctp-bug-don-t-combine-multiple-awaits-in-one-statement.aspx). It never was meant to be used in production, it's just a *technology preview*.

The beta does not contain this specific bug, but I still would be very careful when using it.

Also, depending on what features of the CTP you are going to use, you might need to make changes to your code to make it work under .Net 4.5 beta (or, presumably, the final release), [because there were some changes between the CTP and the beta](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/03/06/eduasync-20-changes-between-the-vs11-preview-and-the-visual-studio-11-beta.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I looked deeply in decompiled methods with async/await syntax (the oonly feature we need from async ctp) and it just compiler magic (maybe very few runtime changes) that creates new class where all await statements starts in different threads. So I think it's quite safe to use it until 4.5 release.